# ffmpeg Reduce frame rate

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to convert h264 vids to h265. Some of the vids are 50fps and seem to have a lot of duplicate frames(100000+). I guess these are 25fps vids and somehow they have every frame duplicated.

ffmpeg is not dropping the frames it seems and so I guess this is wasting space(although I'd hope very little but it's probably not optimal).

I'd like to fix this though.

is there a way to set the frame rate to 30, say(-r 30) and have ffmpeg correctly keep everything in sync(audio aligned properly) and not have any real issues? this might require interpolation and all that but I definitely do not want the audio to be off(it's crucial) and I don't want the length to change.

I'm not sure if I can just specify -r 30 and everything will work out, if it even matters(maybe h265 handles these duplicates very efficiently?), or if I need to specify more?

So, in some sense, I'm actually increasing the frame rate(if it is 25fps and I'm going to 30, hence the interpolation).

I also have a lot of videos that this happened to. Is there any efficient way to go back and recode them if necessary?

What are the compression consequences of having these duplicate frames in h265? Does it store them very efficiently or am I wasting space?

I have a few hundred GB of files and probably a lot have this issue as I didn't know what was going on and didn't investigate it but saw the message a lot. I actually thought it was just some meaningless error since it was clear the video was consistent with the other. If 100k duplicate frames would imply a static video but it didn't occur to me that someone would duplicate every frame(since that would simply waste space). [I tried to search but little exists about this specific issue]

Comment: How are you not sure if `-r 30` will work out? What did it do when you tried that?

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson I'm not sure, but I don't want to use it and it not work and waste an hour converting a video. This is why I asked. It seems -r does not actually do any interpolation and so it doesn't seem to be a great option when one can interpolate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an output rate different than input rate, ffmpeg, by default, will duplicate or drop frames; no interpolation occurs unless you specifically use a filter like minterpolate or framerate.

x264, and similarly, x265 store duplicate frames efficiently - we're talking < 100 bytes for a duplicate frame.

Comment: How does it manage keeping things properly in sync with dropping or duplicating frames? Doesn't this create micro timing issues? We are talking about 3/5 error accumulating (50 fps to 30fps). I guess it drops and adds frames to keep things in sync over all, e.g., every 15 frames things should line up.

Comment: Do you know of the proper command to make all this work optimally? And will interpolation significantly increase compression time? I run about 1:1 so if it doubles the time it is not worth it.

Comment: You'll always have micro timing issues when converting from one rate to another. Overall sync is maintained since output timestamps are assigned based on the output timestamp 'slot' closest to the source timestamp.

Comment: Yes, but the devil is in the details. If it's on the order of seconds then it is an issue, if it is ms then it is not. If it resyncs every 3/5 of a second then that is noticeable. It depends on the algorithm. I'm sure ffmpeg does a good job and would duplicate or drop frames in such a way as to minimize issues but I'm looking for a way to get the most out of ffmpeg by the appropriate commands. Is -r 30 enough? What about when when one has 29.95? This makes it even worse if the algorithm is too basic. Timing could get progressively off. lcm(3000,2995) = 1797000.

Comment: It's also not as simple as "try it"... because I am batch converting and won't be able to look at every video... and since there is a wide variety of video encoding some may fail to work correctly and go unnoticed until after the source has been deleted.

Comment: It does so every frame. FFmpeg has been used for more than a decade by many platforms and media pipelines, including Youtube, Vimeo, Netflix..etc. I'm sure it would have been noticed by now if the error was egregious :)

Comment: 29.95 won't make a difference. The notation is actually 29.97 and the exact framerate is 30000/1001. For 23.976 and 59.94, it is 24000/1001 and 60000/1001 respectively. `-r 30` is fine.

Comment: For example, I just encoded a video and it basically seems to repeat every second over and over but the timing moves forward. It's like it repeats about 5 times then moves to the next part of the video then repeats 5 times and the next part... each part about a second long... The video is totally screwed up and unusable and happens on several players. This video was converted with ffmpeg without -r. It might have been due to converting a series of vobs using mkvtoolnix. I have no idea, just checked it and it was doing it. This is the kinda crap I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: That sounds like a broadcast/satellite dump with malformed video stream. Share the full command and its  log (add -report to generate the log).

Comment: It has a fps of 59.940064 and the first 2 mins of the video seem to be good. It seems that there is some fucked up issue where the audio and video are not correct but some dumb algorithm decides to duplicate the audio in chunks to make sure it fits with the video. This is because when I go to the end, the audio is fine but the video is playing 3x faster.

Comment: I've already converted it, it happened a earlier today, maybe yesterday. I deleted the source. I've converted 100+ videos and every one I have checked out works. Most were mp4's but a few were DVD's that I went ahead and merged using mkvtoolnix-gui. I believe this one one of the DVD's. I'm trying to recover the file without success(seems windows chose to overwrite the most recent deletions rather than the oldest... another moronic algorithm).

Comment: Ok, the original dvd has the problem when played from vobs. Must be some encryption. When I try too play the DVD in vlc it's basically a green screen(but audio is correct). I watched the video a long time ago though... So nothing I said above was ultimately correct. I gotta figure out some way to get it to convert properly.